# Material UI component written is function based component?

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to use material ui component into react class based component material ui component demo everthing wrtten function based but we are written all project pages are class based very difficult to integrating material UI component

Comment: Why do you use class components ? i think functional components are too much faster in execution.@user2829028

Answer (score 1):

It is not difficult to integrate on class-based Components. yes, In Material UI doc all the things have integrated on functional-based Components with using Hooks. But you should have some Knowledge about hooks and state concepts then you can easily be integrated them.
for example:

```
  export default function AlertDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open alert dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{"Use Google's location service?"}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous location 
         data to
            Google, even when no apps are running.
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Disagree
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
            Agree
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So, this Dialog Code has written in functional Based Components  But we can easily integrated on class based component Like:

```
 export default  class  AlertDialog extends React.Components{
  constructor(){

 super(props)
this.state={
    open:false
    }
  }


  handleClickOpen = () => {
    this.setState({open:true})
  };

  handleClose = () => {
       this.setState({open:false})
  };
render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open alert dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        open={this.state.open}
        onClose={this.handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{"Use Google's location service?"}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous location 
         data to
            Google, even when no apps are running.
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
            Disagree
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
            Agree
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

So, just we should have Knowledge about basic React Concept and you can do this.

Comment: i have written one class based component home page. i need  material UI select option and  table so i have created two function based component i am calling this two child component into home page. so we are creating each ui component each function based component page they are increasing chilld component.